# Mixing variable assigment and data retrieval - MySQL vs MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to refresh my skills with sql queries, which I have not used in many years.

While making some excercises I came across a problem which is quite simple to solve in MySql but more complicated in sql server. I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to do it.

I will oversimplify the problem for the sake of the question (to avoid complicated code)

So, I have a sequence of numbers. Within this sequence I want to identify and number subsequences of numbers < 10. When a number >= 10 is met a new subsequence starts identified by the seqno counter. Below the mysql query + result

```
create table myt1(mynum int);
insert into myt1 values (13), (5), (8), (15), (2), (5), (18), (3), (6), (9), (8), (12);
set @seqno = 0;
select mynum, @seqno := case when mynum < 10 then @seqno else @seqno+1 end as seqno
from myt1
```

[image: Here is the result]

Now with SQL server things get more complicated because it's not allowed to do in the same SELECT statement both data retrieval and variable assignment. My workaround to get the same result was to copy the table into a temp table with an additional column and then update the table/colum with the following code

```
create table myt1(mynum int);
insert into myt1 values (13), (5), (8), (15), (2), (5), (18), (3), (6), (9), (8), (12);
select *, 1 as seqno
into #tempt1
from myt1 

declare @seqno int;
set @seqno = 0;
update #tempt1
set 
    seqno = @seqno, 
    @seqno = case when mynum < 10 then @seqno else @seqno+1 end

select * from #tempt1
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a simpler way to write this query in mssql and why there is a limitation that is not found in mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: So,eone at mysql that something like this is usefull and it was implemented, today with mysql 8 you would switch to window functions. MSQL has also such window functions see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a cumulative count of the values over 10:

```
select mynum,
       sum(case when mynum >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as seqno
from myt1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8baa96d0b2a42ed0566c01b7bf195f72) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your query assumes an ordering of the table -- which is not valid in SQL in general or in either database.  Your query does *seem* to work in MySQL, but there are no guarantees.

I have added an `id` column to capture the ordering, so the query will work.

Incidentally, this is also the preferred method in MySQL 8+; the use of variables is being deprecated.

Comment: And Sql Server has supported this _correct_ and _standard_ method since back in 2012, while MySql only just got window functions and before that had _no way at all_ to do this that would guarantee correct ordering: again, it only seemed to work most of the time because of an accident in the way data was stored on disk or in memory, and a query where you suddenly hit a different index might tempt the engine to completely break MySqls results using the old method.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . Actually, this particular problem can be solved using correlated subqueries, so there has always been a solution in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I didnt think the sum+over combo and,sorry,as I stated in my Q, I wanted to oversimplify,so dropped the id ordering column which is very important, my mistake. But I quickly added 'id' to my original query here  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8a8c565c88ca25b33e0ed68b093b0be  is there any problem now with this query?  I ask this especially to @JoelCoehoorn who seem to say my original query is inherently broken because using a variable instead of a windowed func.